# Why does my bare-metal VM only receive broadcast packets from its bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, qemu

I have attached one of my nics to a bridge in netplan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
[...]
    eth1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eth1]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      parameters:
        stp: false
```

That side of things behaves as expected, if I do a `tcpdump -i br0` I can see every packet that arrives on eth1 on my bridge. However, if I tell QEMU to attach a (bare-metal, literally a while-true loop which receives packets from a virtio device) VM to it, I only receive broadcast packets in the VM:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -kernel target/aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat/debug/router -s -machine virt -cpu cortex-a53 -nographic -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:55555,server,nowait -netdev bridge,br=br0,id=ingress -device virtio-net-device,netdev=ingress
```

While that command is running, I can see a new virtual interface (tap0) which appears to be connected to the bridge just fine, but if I do a `tcpdump -i tap0` I can clearly see that only broadcast packets from eth1 are going to tap0.

What is preventing my packets from arriving in tap0/my vm, and how can I make all packets arrive in tap0? I already tried ebtable-prerouting shenanigans to change the destination mac address of incoming packets to tap0's mac address, but with no success.

Comment: Did you enable the promiscuous mode of the vNIC of your VM? Otherwise, packets will be filtered, that are not destinated for your VM.

Comment: Filtered by the host kernel? Shouldn't an ebtables rule that changes the destination mac to the vNIC's of the VM stop that filtering?